# How to fix the false beats of piano

Tags: piano, tuning

I have tuned my old piano several times. Now the only problem I have is that there are few keys that have false beats. I looked for solutions from YouTube. The answer I got was using CA glue on the pin. I tried it but it didn't work very well in the end. Can anyone tell me more effective method to fix this problem with false beats?

Comment: Seems like it's a piano with a wooden frame, where the pins are in wood. There is no solution - get one with an iron frame.

Comment: @Time Thanks for your answer. I didn't know that there exist pianos with iron frames. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Tim even if there's an iron frame, the pins are in a wooden block.  Libertarian Monarchist Bot: what do you mean by "false beat"?

Comment: @phoog If I mute the other two strings, there's still "wa~wa~wa" beats sounds while I play a single string.

Comment: Aha.  That is indeed interesting and puzzling.  I forgot to say that pianos that _lack_ iron frames are very rare these days, either antiques or copies of antiques.  When was your piano made?  Is it possible that other strings are vibrating sympathetically, a fifth or an octave apart from the one you're tuning?  What is the pitch you're trying to tune, and what is the frequency of the beating you hear?

Comment: @phoog Thanks for your comments. My parents bought me the piano in early 2000. So I guess it was made in late 1990s. What do you mean by other strings vibrating sympathetically? I dont remember the pitch. There were several treble strings that have false beats, but I cannot tell the frequencies because I've never trained in piano tuning. I use my Tunelab, which doesn't tell me the frequence of the beats.

Comment: By frequency of the beats I mean how many beats you hear per second.  As the string goes "wa-wa-wa," how many "wa's" happen in a given period of time?  By sympathetic vibration I mean the vibration that you hear if you, for example, press middle C slowly and silently so the damper is not touching the strings, then strike the C below sharply and release it quickly.  The middle C strings will be left vibrating; this vibration is called "sympathetic."

Comment: If your piano was made in the 1990s, it surely has a metal frame unless it was sold as a "fortepiano."  See http://pianotuninginyork.blogspot.com/2016/10/feeling-tension-1-why-piano-has-high.html for a picture of a cast-iron frame that has been removed from the wooden case.

Comment: @phoog I tried to count the number of beats per second but I found it so difficult to do this job. I am wondering how piano technicians do this. The sound will fade away, so how should I count the number of beats within a second? I still don't know what "sympathetic" means. I don't hear anything after releasing it quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

False beats in a piano string are from stresses or inconsistencies in the steel of the string. You need to replace the string. Call a piano tech and have it done. You can diy but you need a micrometer to figure out what gauge wire to order and you will need to order 1/4 lb.because it's the smallest amount you can order. Then there are some basic tools that would help and you can find out how it's done from YouTube or piano tech literature. Remember: In the context of the music you are playing, you'll never notice it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We don't have any piano tech who is capable of doing this work in my city.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, every piano string should have a false beat, though it is usually much more obvious in the treble.  If you ask 100 piano technicians what is the cause and what is the cure you will likely get 100 answers.  As stated before: "In the context of the music you are playing, you'll never notice it."  In my 50 years of tuning I have only had 2 customers actually notice false beats. My personal opinion: the less one does to bend, kink, mutilate or damage a string the better.  I find new, inexpensive pianos usually have fewer false beats than expensive older instruments that have been "fixed" by many well-meaning technicians.

Comment: Thank you for your information.